# Is there any tools to predict the potential RNA candidate that can bind to a protein?

Tags: proteins, rna

I have a list of RNA binding proteins from HyDRa prediction. I have a long list of mRNA, I'm interested in.

For the list of RNA binding proteins, I want to find the potential RNA binding partners. Lets say each protein can bind to 5-20 RNAs, I want to find this list.
Now for each RNA-protein binding, I want to calculate the binding affinity or any equivalent measurement.
Is there any tools, I can use to do this? or any related insilico approach I can try?

Comment: Almost certainly I would look at published machine learning studies